# Set route in different directories Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, controller, routes

Divided  controllers into folders, site in site folder, admin in admin folder (inside controllers).

But I can not access the controllers without putting the base of the same folder url, example:

I want to access like this: `http://localhost/gabriel/projeto/about`

But just so I can: `http://localhost/gabriel/projeto/site/about`

File 'htaccess' this so:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

'base_url' this so:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/gabriel/projeto/';
```

File 'routes' this so:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site/index/";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = "admin/login";
```

Already tried modifying the .htaccess but no result.
Inserting another line in the file 'routes':

```
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
```

But putting that line it conflicts with the route ends and the Admin can receive only one parameter in Url.

How can I solve this problem? make dynamic route...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're asking, but try setting the base_url in the config/config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/gabriel/projeto/';
```

or set to whatever you want your site root to be

Answer (score 0):

add this in your routes.php.. place it above all other $route variable...

```
$route['projeto/about'] = 'projeto/site/about';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem as well:

```
$route['admin/(.*)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['(.*)'] = "site/$1";
```

Now this dynamic route